# MySQL Joing Two tables with count value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following two tables and Queries:

```
 select UserId,UserName, from ch_userregistration 

 select  ReceiverId, COUNT(Message) from ch_singleconversation WHERE 
 SenderId = '1002' AND MsgStatus='Y' GROUP BY ReceiverId
```

First table Like ,

```
UserId  UserNeme`
-----------------
1001    Mohan
1002    Raj
1003    Mahesh
1004    rahul
```

Second Table Like

```
ReceiverId    Count
---------------------------
 1002           8
 1004           4
```

I Want the result like this

```
UserId   UserName   Count
----------------------------
1001    Mohan        0
1002    Raj          8
1003    Mahesh       0
1004    rahul        4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *outer* type join specifically `LEFT JOIN` since you wanted to display all rows in table `ch_userregistration` even if it has no matches in table `ch_singleconversation`.

```
SELECT  a.UserId, 
        a.UserName,
        COUNT(b.Message) AS `Count`
FROM    ch_userregistration a
        LEFT JOIN ch_singleconversation b
            ON  b.senderId = '1002' 
                AND b.MsgStatus = 'Y'
                AND a.UserId = b.ReceiverId
GROUP   BY a.UserId, a.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) the data from the two queries with subqueries:

```
SELECT A.UserId, A.UserName, B.MessageCount
FROM
   (SELECT UserId, UserName 
    FROM ch_userregistration) A
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT ReceiverId, COUNT(Message) MessageCount
    FROM ch_singleconversation 
    WHERE 
    SenderId='1002' AND MsgStatus='Y' 
    GROUP BY ReceiverId) B
ON A.UserId=B.ReceiverId;
```

OR:

```
SELECT A.UserId, A.UserName, B.MessageCount
FROM
   ch_userregistration A
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT ReceiverId, COUNT(Message) MessageCount
    FROM ch_singleconversation 
    WHERE 
    SenderId='1002' AND MsgStatus='Y' 
    GROUP BY ReceiverId) B
ON A.UserId=B.ReceiverId;
```

OR:

```
SELECT A.UserId, A.UserName, COUNT(B.Message) MessageCount
FROM
   ch_userregistration A
LEFT JOIN
   ch_singleconversation B
ON A.UserId=B.ReceiverId
WHERE B.SenderId='1002' AND B.MsgStatus='Y' 
GROUP BY A.UserId, A.UserName;
```